# margin: 0 auto not working on mobile device

Tags: html, css

We developed website http://www.topuctovnici.sk and it seems to have a problem with mobile device and centering  content with margin: 0 auto and defined concrete width.

It looks like this: http://i60.tinypic.com/23vnqd4.png "topuctovnici.sk"

I have no idea where is problem, because .core has 1240px width and after this there is a div with width 1000px and margin: 0 auto and it does nothing on mobile device.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can we see some more of the code such as the css and HTML for the areas where the problem lies. It will more than likely be a very simple fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always do this:

```
#main-wrapper {
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 1000px;
}
```

That way mobile devices are filled 100% and on large screens your content is max. 1000px wide. Then your horizontal centering should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try max-width instead of width for your fixed with values.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say where exactly the css and HTML markup is crashing, but you can try the following:

Set your div with 1000px to inline-block element.

```
<div style="width: 1000px!important; display: inline-block;">
```

And in your parent `.core` div set the css property text-aling: to center

```
.core {
    width: 1240px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```